# How do I make some columns in a chart stack while keeping others separate?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Javascript Highcharts, and am trying to make a chart that contains column and line series. I have 3 column series, and I want 2 of them to stack. I want the 3rd one to stay by itself. Is this possible? I tried putting them on different y axes, but they still all stack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After tons more searching, I found the answer in an unexpected place.

You can use the "stack:" series option to group things to stack together.

```
{ name: 'series1', data: 'data1', stack: 'stack12' },
{ name: 'series2', data: 'data2', stack: 'stack12' },
{ name: 'series3', data: 'data3', stack: 'stack3' }
```

In this example, series1 and series2 would stack, while series 3 would stay separate.